# Filter null values of two populations in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

**MAIN GOAL**

I want to retrieve translations, which are projected as terms (`Term`) with a single relation (`Relation`) in between.

**STATUS**

I'm describing terms `Term`. Think of it as words (usually nouns).

```
const TermSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  _id:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,  
  term: { type: String, required: true },
  lang: { type: String, required: true},
  relations: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Relation' }],
});

export default mongoose.model<Term & mongoose.Document>('Term', TermSchema);
```

The `Relation` schema describes the relations of these terms.

```
const RelationSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    _id:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,  
    relationType: { type: String, required: true, default: RelationEnum.TRANSLATION },
    termSrc: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Term'  },
    termTrg: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Term'  },    
  });

export default mongoose.model<Relation & mongoose.Document>('Relation', RelationSchema);
```

I want to retrieve all translations from a language combination. Let's say German (`de`) and Arabic (`ar`). That is:

1. Retrieve all relations with the `relationType` of value `RelationEnum.TRANSLATION`.
2. Populate the termSrc where language is either de or ar.
3. Populate the termTrg where language is either de or ar.

Which led me to write the following mongoose statement.

```
var query = Relation.find({relationType: 'TRANSLATION' }, null)
                .populate( {path: 'termSrc', select: 'term lang', model: Term, match: {lang: {$in: ['ar', 'de']}}})
                .populate( {path: 'termTrg', select: 'term lang', model: Term, match: {lang: {$in: ['ar', 'de']}}});
```

In most cases that certainly results in what I'm aiming for. Here is a desired sample of a single records, which is returned.

```
    {
        "_id": "41224d776a326fb40f000023",
        "relationStatus": "QUALIFIED",
        "termSrc": {
            "_id": "41224d776a326fb40f000021",
            "term": "Verhaftung",
            "lang": "de"
        },
        "termTrg": {
            "_id": "41224d776a326fb40f000022",
            "term": "اعتقالات",
            "lang": "ar"
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

Since the population of termSrc and termTrg are fully independent (it is like an OR statement, a disjunction), it will also include relations where only one filter applies to the population. Thus the query will also return records for French-Arabic translations. Of course, setting the `fr` term to null (because we look for `'ar', 'de'`) as in this sample record.

```
   {
        "_id": "01224d776a326fb40f000050",
        "relationStatus": "QUALIFIED",
        "termSrc": null,
        "termTrg": {
            "_id": "01224d776a326fb40f000034",
            "term": "تقالا",
            "lang": "ar"
        }
    }
```

Which is not what I desire and leads to an after-math cleanup. I only want de-ar and ar-de translations.

As my main goal expresses, I'd like to have only relations returned where BOTH terms are populated (none of them should be `null`).

- Could one 1) run the `find` then both `populate` then 2) run a filter on the intermediate result to avoid `null` records?
- If it cannot be accomplished with intermediate queries, how can one achive this using aggregates, hence filter all the relations with null records in either termSrc and termTrg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below `$lookup` version

```
  Relation.aggregate([
    { $match: { relationType: "TRANSLATION" } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Term.collection.name,
        let: { termSrc: "$termSrc" },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$termSrc"] } } }],
        as: "termSrc"
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$termSrc" },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Term.collection.name,
        let: { termTrg: "$termTrg" },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$termTrg"] } } }],
        as: "termTrg"
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$termTrg" }
  ]);
```